# Drawing SVG on scroll with skrollr

Tags: javascript, css, svg, skrollr

I'm trying to draw a simple svg as the user scrolls down on the viewport. I'm using [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) because it's meant to be simple, but I can not make it work.

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 1610.2 1604.6" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1610.2 1604.6;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#1D1D1D;}
    .st1{fill:none;stroke:#666666;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st2{fill:none;stroke:#666666;stroke-width:1.0674;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st3{fill:#666666;}
    .st4{fill:url(#SVGID_1_);stroke:#666666;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st5{fill:#161616;stroke:#666666;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st6{fill:url(#SVGID_2_);stroke:#666666;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st7{fill:#F7F7F7;}
</style>

<rect data-0="stroke-dashoffset:1500;" data-end="stroke-dashoffset:0;"  x="-397.1" y="-1042.5" class="" width="447.4" height="295"/>
<line data-0="stroke-dashoffset:1500;" data-end="stroke-dashoffset:0;"  class="st1" x1="-400" y1="-988.5" x2="-86" y2="-988.5"/>
<line data-0="stroke-dashoffset:1500;" data-end="stroke-dashoffset:0;"  class="st1" x1="-7" y1="-989" x2="50.3" y2="-988.5"/>
<rect data-0="stroke-dashoffset:1500;" data-end="stroke-dashoffset:0;"  x="-74.5" y="-1016.3" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 685.2816 -322.584)" class="st2" width="55.5" height="55.5"/>
<path  data-0="stroke-dashoffset:1500;" data-end="stroke-dashoffset:0;"  class="st3" d="M-46.8-1025.2L-46.8-1025.2c-1.4,0-2.6-1.1-2.6-2.6l0,0c0-1.4,1.1-2.6,2.6-2.6h0c1.4,0,2.6,1.1,2.6,2.6l0,0
    C-44.2-1026.3-45.3-1025.2-46.8-1025.2z"/>
<path data-0="stroke-dashoffset:1500;" data-end="stroke-dashoffset:0;"   class=" st3" d="M-46.8-946.9L-46.8-946.9c-1.4,0-2.6-1.1-2.6-2.6l0,0c0-1.4,1.1-2.6,2.6-2.6h0c1.4,0,2.6,1.1,2.6,2.6l0,0
    C-44.2-948-45.3-946.9-46.8-946.9z"/>
<path  data-0="stroke-dashoffset:1500;" data-end="stroke-dashoffset:0;"  class="st3" d="M-7.7-985.9L-7.7-985.9c-1.4,0-2.6-1.1-2.6-2.6l0,0c0-1.4,1.1-2.6,2.6-2.6h0c1.4,0,2.6,1.1,2.6,2.6l0,0
    C-5.1-987.1-6.3-985.9-7.7-985.9z"/>
<path data-0="stroke-dashoffset:1500;" data-end="stroke-dashoffset:0;"  class="st3" d="M50.3-986.2L50.3-986.2c-1.2,0-2.2-1-2.2-2.2l0,0c0-1.2,1-2.2,2.2-2.2h0c1.2,0,2.2,1,2.2,2.2l0,0
    C52.6-987.3,51.6-986.2,50.3-986.2z"/>
<path data-0="stroke-dashoffset:1500;" data-end="stroke-dashoffset:0;"  class="st3" d="M-86-985.9L-86-985.9c-1.4,0-2.6-1.1-2.6-2.6l0,0c0-1.4,1.1-2.6,2.6-2.6l0,0c1.4,0,2.6,1.1,2.6,2.6l0,0
    C-83.4-987.1-84.6-985.9-86-985.9z"/>
<linearGradient data-0="stroke-dashoffset:1500;" data-end="stroke-dashoffset:0;"   id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="885.6667" y1="-1039.5" x2="885.6667" y2="-410.7027">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#212121"/>
    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#212121"/>
</linearGradient>
<polygon data-0="stroke-dashoffset:1500;" data-end="stroke-dashoffset:0;"  class="st4" points="50.3,-1042.5 50.3,-378.5 1721,-1040.5 "/>
<polygon class="st5" points="1721,-1040.5 2302.9,-1040.5 1564.7,-747.5 981.6,-747.5 "/>
<linearGradient id="SVGID_2_" data-0="stroke-dashoffset:1500;" data-end="stroke-dashoffset:0;"  gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="1564.6666" y1="-894" x2="2302.9167" y2="-894">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#212121"/>
    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#212121"/>
</linearGradient>
<polygon  data-0="stroke-dashoffset:1500;" data-end="stroke-dashoffset:0;"  class="st6" points="2302.9,-747.5 2302.9,-1040.5 1564.7,-747.5 "/>
<rect x="393" y="-926.5" class="st7" width="593" height="434"/>
<g data-0="stroke-dashoffset:1500;" data-end="stroke-dashoffset:0;" >
    <polyline class="st1" points="2.5,0 2.5,162 43.2,162 43.2,30 748.7,30 748.7,162 916.7,162 1516.8,162 1607.7,162 1607.7,911.1
        1512.8,911.1 1512.8,778.1 815.8,778.1 815.8,912.1 641.7,912.1 293.8,912.1 293.8,1264.1 293.8,1597.1 343.3,1597.1 343.3,1462.1
        1040.8,1462.1 1040.8,1602.1 1108.2,1602.1   "/>
    <circle class="st3" cx="2.5" cy="162" r="2.5"/>
    <circle class="st3" cx="43.2" cy="162" r="2.5"/>
    <circle class="st3" cx="748.7" cy="162" r="2.5"/>
    <circle class="st3" cx="1512.9" cy="778.1" r="2.5"/>
    <circle class="st3" cx="1512.8" cy="911" r="2.5"/>
    <circle class="st3" cx="1607.7" cy="911" r="2.5"/>
    <circle class="st3" cx="815.8" cy="778.4" r="2.5"/>
    <circle class="st3" cx="815.7" cy="912.1" r="2.5"/>
    <circle class="st3" cx="293.8" cy="1597" r="2.5"/>
    <circle class="st3" cx="343.5" cy="1597" r="2.5"/>
    <circle class="st3" cx="343.2" cy="1462.2" r="2.5"/>
    <circle class="st3" cx="1040.8" cy="1462" r="2.5"/>
    <circle class="st3" cx="1040.7" cy="1602.1" r="2.5"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Here is a pen to my code:
http://codepen.io/ohmmho/pen/zqjbRW

May be I'm setting the data-end/start points to the wrong elements? There are elements like 'line' and 'rect' that confuse me, I'm learning SVG animations. Some light on this would be appreciated.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after a further research, I found out what I was doing wrong: Those **shape elements like circle or polygon need to be paths** in order to accomplish what I'm trying. You can export your svg file from Illustrator properly or convert them with some tools, more info on this [here](https://css-tricks.com/lodge/svg/26-forcing-shapes-paths/).

My codepen works now :D

Answer (score 1):

You can only draw in objects with a stroke.
In your svg only these classed elements have a stroke:

.st1{fill:none;stroke:#666666;stroke-miterlimit:10;}

.st2{fill:none;stroke:#666666;stroke-width:1.0674;stroke-miterlimit:10;}

You also need to offset this stroke with css:

style="stroke-dasharray:2000;stroke-dashoffset:2000"

And try these attribute values-  you can use any of the Skrollr options: 
(you are either moving the line from a value off set to 0, or from 0 to an offset (to draw out an object)

data-top="stroke-dashoffset:0;"
    data-center-top="stroke-dashoffset:2000;"

Comment: thanks Jordan, you are right: the elements need to have an stroke and they need to be **paths** not shapes in order to have an stroke and fill it.